# Can't install NuGet packages in Xamarin Forms

Tags: xamarin.forms, nuget-package

I am trying to install a NuGet package in Xamarin Forms and in all the ones I try to install I get the same error.

***"Package X is not compatible with netstandard2.0"***

[[image: Screenshot of the error.]


<sup>click to enlarge</sup>](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QJXJ8.png)

The package I want to install is this: https://www.nuget.org/packages/Refractored.FloatingActionButton/.

Any idea how to fix this error?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The plugin **Refractored.FloatingActionButton** is for Xamarin.Android . In your case you need to install the package **Refractored.FloatingActionButtonForms**

[image]